# Why does this compound have two benzene rings?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, lewis-structure

If we look at carbons 1 and 2, they have 5 electrons. 3 are directly involved in bonding, and 2 are involved in delocalisation to create the 2 benzene rings. This would mean that they had 5 valence electrons, which isn't possible, and thus there should be only one benzene ring.

[image: Naphthalene]

Comment: These are _not_ benzene rings, and even calling them aromatic because of Huckel's rule is a bit of a stretch. Yet still they are rings, and they contain delocalized bonds, so why not draw them with a circle.

Comment: If you really need a Lewis structure, use the one without rings, with 5 double bonds, and have on mind that it os one of may so called *resonance structures* that are in reality "averaged".

Answer (score 6):

Chemists are already accustomed to this type of formula, even though it is not absolutely correct. More exact would be drawing all bonds with double solid/dashed bonds to express that the bond order is between 1 and 2, approximately 1.5, but is almost never done

[image: naphthalene picture 1]

Rarely can be seen formula with the two circles merged (and maybe dashed also), like

[image: naphthalene picture 2]

But the electrons are in fact delocalized across all bonds of the polycycle structure in "electron cloud" that looks somewhat like the infinity sign ∞ in this case (naphthalene) above and below the planar molecule. What matters is that the count of π (those from the "second bond" of the double bond) electrons is 4n+2 for n is some natural number (here it is n=2). It is a special feature called *aromaticity*, which has something to do with advanced topic of quantum chemistry; and it greatly stabilizes the molecule. Any of these formulas is unable to describe reality.

Comment: Do the two rings in this behave like benzene rings?

Comment: @Saad yes, they have similar properties, but not exactly.. thanks to symmetry, there are there three types of carbon centers (some even do not bear hydrogen atom), while in the benzene there is only one type.

Comment: So the friedel-crafts reactions would work with this?

Comment: @Saad, yes, naphthalene is quite aromatic. Did you at least try to use google? HOWGH

Comment: No, I only just learnt that it's called napthalene.

Comment: Instead of the historical "4n+2 pi electrons", I recommend thinking of Huckel's Rule as "an odd number of pi-electron pairs." Much more intuitive and accessible for new students.

Comment: Well, to nitpick, this one may carry the wrong impression that every carbon on the ring has equal electron density. I don't really think there's a way to be 100% accurate at describing the structure of naphthalene, without drawing out two resonance forms. So your concluding statement is certainly important.

Answer (score -5):

I find this representation to be kind of sloppy for the reason you mentioned. The $\pi$ system is delocalized throughout the molecule, but that doesn't mean it's two aromatic systems.

I find this representation much better:

[image: Alternative representation of naphthalene]

Comment: This one carries the wrong impression that the rings are different, which they are not.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Then how would one represent it? Two 'circles' leave no room to differentiate it from two benzene rings. Also, if these rings aren't benzene rings, then it implies that the one with the OH group attached cannot be called a phenol group?

Do these rings behave like benzene rings though?

Comment: Two circles are fine. There is no such thing as benzene ring. These rings are delocalized; arguably, they are aromatic, albeit to a lesser extent than benzene. In some reactions naphthalene behaves like benzene, and in some it behaves differently.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Arguably we have a problem because our representations all have drawbacks because there is no way to capture the complexity with a few straight lines or circles. Your criticism is nevertheless totally valid.

Comment: Any representation of _anything_ is a simplification and misses some of the complexity. As long as we remember that, we'll be all right.

Comment: Actually, if you treat it as one of two resonance structures, it's good depiction, showcased in Clar's rule.

Comment: Also to @IvanNeretin's concern about lack of symmetry--this doesn't stop anyone from drawing a Kekule structure for benzene. Also, naphthalene under goes Diels-Alder, so this representation is better for that: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja9107275 I would rather just draw out all 6 double bonds, which, looking back at 5 volumes of lab notes, is what I actually did.